# How to use ref keyword when performing mathematical operations with arrays from other methods?

Tags: c#, arrays, reference, ref, operation

I've been trying to implement a program that can take the preassigned values from a 2d array and calculate individual elements within it into 1d arrays, which are then displayed separately from the 2d array.

Here's an example:

```
  public int[,] GetTemperatures()
        {
            int[,] dailyTemperature =
            {
                {38, 40, 42, 34},
                {55, 41, 40, 30},
                {28, 39, 21, 60},
                {61, 52, 43, 42},
                {35, 36, 30, 29},
                {24, 33, 37, 40}
            };

            Console.Write(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyTemperature.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < dailyTemperature.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i].Substring(0, dailyTemperature[i].Length - 1) + " "); 

                for (int j = 0; j < dailyTemperature.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(dailyTemperature[i, j] + "    "); 
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return dailyTemperature;
}
```

```
 public int[] GetTemperatureSum(ref int [,] dailyTemperature)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < temperatureSum.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                int[] temperatureSum = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
                temperatureSum[0] = dailyTemperature[0, 0] + dailyTemperature[0, 1] + dailyTemperature[0, 2] + dailyTemperature[0, 3];
                temperatureSum[1] = dailyTemperature[1, 0] + dailyTemperature[1, 1] + dailyTemperature[1, 2] + dailyTemperature[1, 3];
                temperatureSum[2] = dailyTemperature[2, 0] + dailyTemperature[2, 1] + dailyTemperature[2, 2] + dailyTemperature[2, 3];
                temperatureSum[3] = dailyTemperature[3, 0] + dailyTemperature[3, 1] + dailyTemperature[3, 2] + dailyTemperature[3, 3];
                temperatureSum[4] = dailyTemperature[4, 0] + dailyTemperature[4, 1] + dailyTemperature[4, 2] + dailyTemperature[4, 3];
                temperatureSum[5] = dailyTemperature[5, 0] + dailyTemperature[5, 1] + dailyTemperature[5, 2] + dailyTemperature[5, 3];

                Console.Write(temperatureSum[i] + " ");

            }
            return temperatureSum;
        }
```

The former is the first method from which I am pulling the values. I'm trying to add the sums from each of the 6 rows, resulting in a horizontal 1d array with six elements. The latter is the second method, in which I am adding the sums of these temperatures in each of the rows.

However, I am receiving a CS7036 error stating "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'dailyTemperature' of 'Weather.GetTemperatureSum(ref int [*,*])'"

Weather being the class within which I am trying to implement this in. I am executing the program within the Main() in a do...while loop, invoking both of these methods within in order to display the arrays.

I'd love it if someone could help me with this, as I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now.

Comment: Well, you used `ref int [,] dailyTemperature` as your method parameter. Why _exactly_ did you choose to do that instead of just `int [,] dailyTemperature`?

Comment: It's because I'm only trying to access int [,] dailyTemperature and use its elements to generate my sums. As far as I understand, using ref is supposed to allow this to happen. Also I asked a previous question here and this person acted like I was an idiot for using a 2d parameter when I'm returning a 1d array.

Comment: No, that's not the purpose of `ref` and that is not what `ref` allows you to do. This is a complete misconception of what `ref` actually does. I think it is best you forget everything you believe about `ref`. As a start, can you provide any evidence that you cannot access `int [,] dailyTemperature` and use its elements to generate the sums without the use of the `ref` keyword?

Comment: @ronalddonaldronald Quick question, in your `GetTemperatures()` function, why do you return the array `dailyTemperature` since it is not modified?

Comment: @JonathanBarraone, "_why do you return the array dailyTemperature since it is not modified_" Huh? It's created there in the GetTemperatures method, right at the start of that method...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace my question is why would he return an array that is hard-coded into the function?

Comment: @JonathanBarraone The array IS modified within the function using data from the input array. Literally the first 6 lines following its initialization are assignments to the elements in the array.

Comment: You don't show the line of code that's causing the error, but presumably you're not passing an array to the method correctly. Please show the line that's causing the error.

Comment: It looks like you're iterating over the wrong array in the `for` loop in the `GetTemperatureSum` method. Also, if you want to access `temperatureSum` outside of the `for` loop (i.e. as a return value), then you need to declare it outside the `for` loop. Currently its scope is restricted to the `for` loop only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `ref` keyword here, you can just pass the array normally. Collection types are passed by reference anyway, but you should probably read up on what `ref` means here: **[ref (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)**

There are a few problems with the code, however. First, it looks like you're iterating over the wrong array in the `for` loop in the `GetTemperatureSum` method. You should be iterating over the input array values.

Second, if you want to access `temperatureSum` outside of the `for` loop (i.e. as a return value), then you need to declare it outside the `for` loop. Currently its scope is restricted to the `for` loop only. The code as written won't compile.

To solve the actual problem of adding up the values in the multi-dimensional array, we should first consider iterating over both the dimensions in order to add up the values for each "parent" dimension. To do this, we can use a nested `for` loop, where the outer loop iterates over the first dimesnion (a set of days), and the inner loop iterates over the inner dimension (the days in the current set). Then we can just add the values from each set to the value in the proper dimension of our input array (which should be initialized to the number of sets, or the value of the outer dimension of the input array).

For example:

```
public static int[] GetTemperatureSum(int[,] dailyTemperature)
{
    // Create an array to hold the sums of each set of days
    int[] temperatureSum = new int[dailyTemperature.GetLength(0)];

    // Loop over each set of days
    for (int set = 0; set < dailyTemperature.GetLength(0); set++)
    {
        // Loop over each day in the set
        for (int day = 0; day < dailyTemperature.GetLength(1); day++)
        {
            // Add this day's temp to our sum for this set
            temperatureSum[set] += dailyTemperature[set, day];
        }
    }

    return temperatureSum;
}
```

Now we can call this method like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] dailyTemperature =
    {
    {38, 40, 42, 34},
    {55, 41, 40, 30},
    {28, 39, 21, 60},
    {61, 52, 43, 42},
    {35, 36, 30, 29},
    {24, 33, 37, 40}
};

    int[] sums = GetTemperatureSum(dailyTemperature);

    for (int set = 0; set < dailyTemperature.GetLength(0); set++)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write($"Set #{set + 1}: ");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;

        for (int day = 0; day < dailyTemperature.GetLength(1); day++)
        {
            Console.Write(dailyTemperature[set, day]);
            if (day < dailyTemperature.GetLength(1) - 1)
            {
                Console.Write(" + ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(" = ");
            }
        }

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(sums[set]);
    }

    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("\nDone. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Hello, firstly I am immensely thankful for your help, although I do have some questions. For one, is it necessary for me to separate the dailyTemperature grid outside of the GetTemperatures() method? Secondly, I'm confused about the part that says "int[] sums = GetTemperatureSum(dailyTemperature);" as I am unsure of what location this is supposed to be in. Is it and all of these for statements intended to be in the Main(), as my initial plan was to have all of these for statements condensed in their own methods. Also, would you say my plan with actually adding all of these variables is...

Comment: doable or would you say that strategy should be scrapped? For instance "            temperatureSum[0] = dailyTemperature[0, 0] + dailyTemperature[0, 1] + dailyTemperature[0, 2] + dailyTemperature[0, 3];" When I tried to implement  "int[] temperatureSum = new int[dailyTemperature.GetLength(0)];" in the GetTemperatureSum method, my code was unable to run as I simultaneously had two different values for temperatureSum.

Comment: If you have the temperature array hard coded inside the method, then what is the point of the method? Letting the user pass in the array of temperature is far more useful.

Comment: The location of `int[] sums = GetTemperatureSum(dailyTemperature);` should be wherever in your code you want to get the sum of a temperate array. Above I have it in the main method because it's just an example.

Comment: The code that displays the values of the temperature and sums arrays should definitely be in a separate method.

Comment: Your plan for adding values is not good because you have hard-coded indexes, which will break if someone passes in a different sized array. You should use loops to iterate over all the values based on the sizes of the dimensions, as in the sample.

Comment: For this particular project, I am required to calculate the sums via the computer rather than to independently do the math and plug the values in, which would be much easier. So essentially that is the root of all of my questions here, would it be possible to add these values together into an array that contains the values of the sum? Even though I will easily know what the values will be, could I have the computer calculate it and put these values inside the array? Also I did decide to split up the GetTemperatureSum method, creating DisplayTemperatureSum that exists solely to display.

Comment: That's exactly what my code does... Loops over all values in both dimension, sums each set, and puts the sun values in a new array that's returned from the function